# JBoss redeploy gives NameNotFoundException: ORB not bound

Tags: jboss, redeploy, orb

I'm running JBoss 6.1.0.Final on a Windows 7 desktop.
When I do a redeploy of my ear I always get a stack like this;

```
16:23:32,560 WARN  [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.StartStopLifecycleAction] Error during stop for jboss-switchboard:appName=foretag-ear,module=foretag-ejb-4.0.0-SNAPSHOT,name=ArbetsstalleDAO: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ORB not bound
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:771) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:779) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.unbind(NamingServer.java:349) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.unbind(NamingContext.java:873) [:5.0.5.Final]
        at org.jboss.util.naming.Util.unbind(Util.java:151) [jboss-common-core.jar:2.2.17.GA]
        at org.jboss.util.naming.Util.unbind(Util.java:141) [jboss-common-core.jar:2.2.17.GA]
        at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.SwitchBoardImpl.unbindFromRelevantContext(SwitchBoardImpl.java:303) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
        at org.jboss.switchboard.mc.SwitchBoardImpl.stop(SwitchBoardImpl.java:102) [:1.0.0-alpha-15]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor432.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_34]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_34]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_34]
```

It's a warning but we beleive it will mess up JNDI-space for various reasons. I've googled this but haven't found much useful info. One recommendation was to run the all configuration but it was the same stacktrace with that config as well.
Any ideas or do you think we can really ignore this stack?

Kind regards,

Jan Gifvars

Comment: Oh, God help you with such an old version of JBoss..